# replace application starting view controller in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I have to a set condition and make two starting points for launching my application.

I want to run

`if(condition1 is true)`
then `display FirstloadViewController`,
otherwise `display viewcontroller`

After the launching method. I have tried this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSUserDefaults *fetchDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger intValue = [fetchDefaults integerForKey:@"kIntegerKey"];
    NSLog(@"%i",intValue);
    if(intValue!=100)
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.firstloadViewController = [[FirstloadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstloadViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.firstloadViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

but this error occurred while running it:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: check the nib name is correct or not that you are using in to code line.

Comment: Any other way to solve this !!!

Comment: The error message text you posted is cut off halfway. Please post the full error message text.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users........../myapplication> (loaded)' with name 'FirstloadViewController''