# call Segue mthod from any point in view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

Hi i have little confusion. i am using below method in my application.how should I call this method from ant other point where i need in same view controller.

```
- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender
```

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824050/how-to-navigation-using-segue/23824094#23824094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method wherever you want to segue Controllers.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifierName" sender:nil];
```

This method will automatically trigger the `prepareForSegue` method as soon as the above statement is encountered.

Comment: the string @"yourSegueIdentifierName" is the same that you set in interface builder to access this segue programmtically (in case you don't know where to find it), it's a _property_ of _UIStoryboardSegue_

Comment: I am aware about it. This was just a random name to guide the OP that here you have to insert your segue identifier name. :)

Comment: haha, i guessed so, the comment wasn't for you, rather for the person who asked the question to avoid possible confusion ;)

Comment: Haha. You got me ! ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217550/replace-application-starting-view-controller-in-ios

can u give me solution for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428629/programatically-set-the-initial-view-controller-using-storyboards. This will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should never call `prepareForSegue` in code. It is called for you.

The method you are looking for is...

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"someSegueIdentifier" sender:nil];
```

This will then be routed into the prepare for segue method.

Comment: you are also right... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217550/replace-application-starting-view-controller-in-ios can u give me solution for this?